# delete folder for all users on Mac

Tags: shell, scripting, osx, users, rm

I'm using below command to delete folder

```
rm -rf /Users/*/Library/Group\ Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User\ Content.localized/Templates.localized/
```

The command is working only for single user. I want to delete user template folder for all users. Templates folder automatically should be deleted for all user created on Mac.

Comment: Can you remove the folder for a second user with a modified command? If yes, please show two or more commands how you could do this for more than one user, one by one.

Comment: Do you not even get a "Permission denied" error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following illustrates one way to accomplish the goal with a script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of users, filtering out service accounts, root, daemon, and nobody...
#
users=$(dscl . list /Users | grep -v -e '_' -e 'root' -e 'daemon' -e 'nobody')

# Loop through the list of users.
for user in "$users"; do
    # Put the path to the directory in a variable.
    # The quotes escape the spaces.
    #
    $dir="/Users/$user/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content.localized/Templates.localized/"

    # For each $user, delete the directory if it exists.
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        rm -rf "$dir"
    fi
done

# These variables are no longer needed.
unset users
unset dir
```

Execute the following portion first to make sure that the list of users is expected and correct.

```
dscl . list /Users | grep -v -e '_' -e 'root' -e 'daemon' -e 'nobody'
```

After creating the script, it probably needs to be executed with `sudo`. If the script name is `script.sh`, then...

```
sudo script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the Syntax!

It should go something like this:

```
for i in $(ls -1b /Users); do
 find "$i/Library/Group Containers/" -name Templates.localized --delete
done
```

Consider a testrun without '--delete' before first live usage.

Comment: Note two things: Don't parse the output of `ls`. Using `/Users/*/Library/...` should be working _just fine_.  Your command would delete _any_ directory (or file) called `Templates.localized`. Also, there is no `--delete` predicate in `find` (it's `-delete`).  This will not solve the user's problem, which is likely permission related.